# eclipse Oxygen 2 "Console" blank

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, console, glassfish-4

I have been having an issue with eclipse oxygen, as I am trying to develop JAVA EE program, it appears that the console is always blank and not responding.

I am using server GlassFish 4.1.0 to connect.

Console view is always blank, I have tried to change multiple output displays but without any changes happened.

I have tried several solutions to try to get this fixed:

- re-installing GlassFish again
- New eclipse updates
- Changing console mode

nothing changes

Looking forward for help

(Note: Using MacOS)

Comment: What should be in the console that isn't?

Comment: it is just blank, doesn't show any processes, errors or anything

Comment: When? What are you doing that should make content appear that is not appearing?

Comment: For example, I have a project which runs on Java, I can see there are some problems as there are errors viewable on the Project Explorer, I believe the standard errors should be viewed on the console, but it is blank

Comment: Is there a way to show Glassfish on console ?

Comment: Are you launching Glassfish from within Eclipse or connecting to a running instance?

Comment: running glassfish within eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few troubleshooting steps you can try:

Verify GlassFish Server Configuration:

Make sure you have properly configured the GlassFish server in Eclipse. Go to the Servers view and check if the GlassFish server is listed and started. If not, try starting it from there.
Double-check the server settings, such as the domain, ports, and paths. Ensure that the server configuration matches the actual installation.
Check Console Configuration:

In Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences.
Navigate to Run/Debug > Console.
Ensure that "Show Console When Standard Output Changes" and "Show Console When Standard Error Changes" are selected.
Try switching the console type. You can choose between "Standard" and "Terminated Launches" to see if either option works.
Clean and Rebuild Project:

Right-click on your project in the Package Explorer view.
Select "Clean" to clean the project.
Once the cleaning is finished, right-click on the project again.
Select "Build Project" to rebuild it.
Try running the program and see if the console displays the output.
Check Console Filters:

Open the Console view in Eclipse if it's not already visible.
Look for a small arrow icon in the Console view toolbar.
Click on it and make sure that "Show Console Filters" is not enabled.
If it's enabled, uncheck it to ensure that the console output is not filtered.
Update Eclipse and Plugins:

Ensure that you have the latest updates for Eclipse and the plugins you are using, including the Java EE and GlassFish-related plugins.
Go to Help > Check for Updates in Eclipse to check for any available updates and install them if necessary.
Try a Different Workspace:

Create a new workspace in Eclipse and import your project into the new workspace.
See if the issue persists in the new workspace. Sometimes workspace-specific settings or configurations can cause problems.